# Groovy - Eclipse reporting BUG! (following Java update)

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I am completely at a loss over this - updated my Java (to version 8, build 91) and now my Groovy project, in an early development stage, simply will not run. (**See answer** The update was a co-incidence)

```
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'Simul.groovy' unexpected NullpointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is an example piece of code:

```
package simul

class Simulation {
    def globalMemory
    def signalNetwork
    def processors
    def blueTree
    def coreArray
    def outputDevice
    def endian
    def coreCount
    static CORE_COUNT = 256
    static TOTAL_MEM_SIZE = 0x100000000
    static DEFAULT_ENDIAN = 0
    static LOCAL_MEM_SIZE = 16
    static LOCAL_MEM_START = 0xA0000000

    Simulation(def cores = this.CORE_COUNT, def memSize = this.TOTAL_MEM_SIZE,
        def endianess = this.DEFAULT_ENDIAN)
    {
        //0 for little endian, 1 for big endian
        endian = endianess
        globalMemory = new MemoryArray(this, memSize, 0)
        coreCount = cores
    }   

}


def stuff = new Simulation()
stuff.coreArray = []
for (coreNumb in 1..stuff.coreCount) {
    stuff.coreArray << new Core(stuff, coreNumb - 1)
}
```

Eclipse merely flags an error on the package line (and does the same for other class files).

I assume this is a problem caused by the Java update but I can find nobody else referencing this issue online (and unfortunately the Groovy email lists seem to be unavailable due to a DNS problem).

Any clues?

**Update**
If I try to run one of the files on its own  eg  `groovyConsole Simul.groovy` it will execute but then complain it cannot see other files in the package. In fact I can do the same inside the IDE (and this error is repeated in ggts also) if I change the package name for the Simul.groovy file. But if I try to compile/run the code with the package names properly specified it fails with this BUG! error.

(This means the problem is similar - in terms of symptoms - to this: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/327479/scriptrunner-bug-exception-in-phase-semantic-analysis-in-source-unit-script40-groovy-bundle-is-uninstalled)

This is the stack trace:

`BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '/Users/adrian/groovy_stuff/simul/src/simul/Simul.groovy' unexpected NullpointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1226)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:651)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:629)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.processToPhase(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:201)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.internal.compiler.ast.GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(GroovyCompilationUnitDeclaration.java:2206)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:1129)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:281)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(GroovyReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:789)
    at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.model.GroovyCompilationUnit.reconcile(GroovyCompilationUnit.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticVerifier$1.visitVariableExpression(StaticVerifier.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression.visit(VariableExpression.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitPropertyExpression(CodeVisitorSupport.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.PropertyExpression.visit(PropertyExpression.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticVerifier.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticVerifier.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructor(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1214)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.StaticVerifier.visitClass(StaticVerifier.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$13.call(CompilationUnit.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1221)
    ... 24 more`

Comment: What version of groovy? What version of Java did you update from?

Comment: Groovy is 2.3: not sure what version of Java but I assume the previous point entry.
I realise I was using quite an old version of the JDK (1.8.0_45) but I have now installed 1.8.92 and still have the issue

Comment: Have you tried a later version of groovy?

Comment: Just trying it now. Just seem to make any difference (yet) but I confess I am struggling to align all the preferences

Comment: Have you tried building it outside of eclipse? Not sure how eclipse compiles groovy

Comment: That appears to work. Or at least it fails for reasons which are mundane. So I suppose my problems are with Eclipse, which is a bit of a nightmare to configure!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the answer is I was referring to static members of the class Simulation in the form of `this.STATIC_MEMBER` as parameters to the class constructor.

As `this` doesn't exist at this point (and is superfluous in any case) this does raise a `NullPointerException` though it is highly confusing that it's flagged at the point of the `package` command.